# How can I get 3 divs in one line? Flex not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put all 3 divs next to each other but it is not happening. I want to align them in one row and have equal spacing between them.
Flex display is not working.
Any idea why is it not working and how can I get all 3 divs in one line?

```css
.package{
 border: solid 1px black;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 height: 500px;
 width: 380px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="packages">PACKAGES</h2>
    <div class="package">
    
    </div>
    <div class="package">
    
    </div>
    <div class="package">
    
    </div>
```

*HTML CODE*

```
<h2 class="packages">PACKAGES</h2>
            <div class="package">

            </div>
            <div class="package">

            </div>
            <div class="package">

            </div>
```

*CSS CODE*

```
.package{
border: solid 1px black;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
height: 500px;
width: 380px;
text-align: center;
```

}

*OUTPUT*

[image: Click here for Output]

Comment: `.package` and `class="packages` are different  **s** ;)  the parent is to be the flex container.

Comment: The div has class="package" to which I'm writing CSS code.

Comment: ...   *the parent is to be the flex container.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container needs to be display Flex. Like so:

```css
.package-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.package {
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 380px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="packages">PACKAGES</h2>
<div class="package-container">
  <div class="package">1</div>
  <div class="package">2</div>
  <div class="package">3</div>
</div>
```